# Require sharepoint 2010 search tool

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am migrating MOSS 2007 site to sharepoint 2010 without UI upgrade. In MOSS 2007, to search a specific keyword from the document uploaded on site we use to use "http://sharepointsearchserv.codeplex.com/" tool. The result use to be in xml format. And I would  fetch the filename of the document from the xml,Now that I am migrating it to 2010 I require  a new tool. Hence I came across this: http://fastforsharepoint.codeplex.com/. But this tool can search only till 10000 records. For next 10000 records it produces below error.

```
 <ResponsePacket xmlns="urn:Microsoft.Search.Response">
  <Response domain="">
    <Status>ERROR_SERVER</Status>
    <DebugErrorMessage>System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]</DebugErrorMessage>
  </Response>
</ResponsePacket>"
```

My query is. Is there any alternate tool which I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I referred http://www.silver-it.com/node/97 link to solve the issue. But speaking about the tool. When I say "save result" it stops working. And when I click on "save all results" it just saves the  code. I want to save the result as xml file. How do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is not with the tool itself, but with the search service.

Check the USL logs to find the cause of the error.